# Get name on listview item clicked

Tags: android, listview

I have got listview with (id, name, image) parsed from json: I'm going to get name when the image clicked, I will get the name but not always sometime get wrong name.

```
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listView.setOnScrollListener(this);
```

adapter code;

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
    TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
    TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
    NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
    FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

    FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

    name.setText(item.getName());
```

code i have so far;

```
   public void clicked(View view) {

    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GalleryUrlActivity.class);
    String message = name.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra("message", message);
    startActivity(i);
```

i will appropriate your help...

Comment: please show your adapter code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set onclicklistner on your image click and then can get name when your image is click. You can set below code in your adapater class getView().

```
  final int pos=position;
    feedImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Log.v("name :: ", feedItems.get(pos). getName());

          Intent i = new Intent(context, GalleryUrlActivity.class);
          String message = feedItems.get(pos). getName();
          i.putExtra("message", message);
          context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: And where does that `position` come from?

Comment: it is position in your adpter getView method i.e. public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

Comment: This will only work when you click the image and not the whole row item. If you change feedImageView to convertView you will get better results.

Comment: @PedroOliveira yes. but in question Riz has mentioned -> "I'm going to get name when the image clicked" so i have given this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This code will set a click listener on the item of the listview. It will use the same array that you used for the adapter.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
        {
           FeedItem myItem = feedItems.get(i);
           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GalleryUrlActivity.class);
           String message = myItem.getName(); //change this according to your feeditem
           intent.putExtra("message", message);
           startActivity(intent );
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's because your adapter is not properly coded. How many items does the listview have if you're populating it with an empty array?

Comment: i have updated, is that possible click the image on the list and get name?

Comment: How many items does your listview have? Because I don't see you populating the `feedItems` array

Comment: more than 20 items, i'm flowing this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/

Comment: Then if you didn't change my code and all feeditems have different names it will work for all rows and not only one.